# PHP Session ( $_SESSION[ ] ) is working even destroy the session

Tags: php, session

Here is a code I destroy the session but it still working.

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $_SESSION['name'] = 'Arfan';

 $_SESSION['second_name'] = 'Haider';

echo 'My full name is '.$_SESSION['name'].$_SESSION['second_name'].'<br/>';

unset($_SESSION['second_name']);// unset the second_name session

echo 'My name is '.$_SESSION['name'].$_SESSION['second_name'].'<br/>';// work fine error popup

session_destroy();// Destroy all the session

echo $_SESSION['name']; // session is working here.
?>
```

As you can see at the end of the code session is also working why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `session_destroy()`, the session cookie is removed and the session is no longer stored on the server. The values in `$_SESSION` may still be available, but they will not be on the next page load.

If you want to clear a session completely, you can use:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://no1.php.net/session_destroy) this is not the case. The cookie is not touched, and the variables in `$_SESSION` *should* be unavailable, or at least that's what I gather from: "To use the session variables again, `session_start()` has to be called."

Comment: @Codemonkey This is exactly the case: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14571041/1068495.

Comment: thats not working dude read the docs as well which works: http://pk1.php.net/session_destroy

Comment: What is so hard to understand about "It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie."?

Comment: @Silox, I think your code should work just fine, I have been using that for a long time now and I have not experienced any problems

Comment: @Silox: In your answer you say that `session_destroy` deletes the cookie, but now you quote from the docs that it doesn't. That's pretty hard to understand

Comment: @Codemonkey: The cookie is not the same as the $_SESSION object ;-)

Answer (score 4):

From [docs](http://php.net/session_destroy):

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

[Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php):

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: same answer is mine too its good !! and working !! basically session holds list of array in cookies so thats a reason they need to destroy all of them as well read the docs .. its good